# flex4: swfloader doesn't properly load games

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, swfloader

I have several flash games that when i load them in my firefox browser they load fine,
but when i load them with swfloader using flex 4 (flash builder) they load until 100% and don't show the start menu.

any ideas how to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the loaded flash and the website that contains the page with the loaded flash where not on the same applicationdomain, besides fixing that.

i added the parameter `SWFLoader.loadForCompatibility=true`

```
 /**
 *  A flag that indicates whether the content is loaded so that it can
 *  interoperate with applications built with a different verion of the Flex compiler.  
 *  Compatibility with other Flex applications is accomplished by loading
 *  the application into a sibling (or peer) ApplicationDomain.
 *  This flag is ignored if the content must be loaded into a different
 *  SecurityDomain.
 *  If <code>true</code>, the content loads into a sibling ApplicationDomain. 
 *  If <code>false</code>, the content loaded into a child ApplicationDomain */
```